# Modal doesn't show up when clicking on edit button and logs don't give any message error in Laravel 8

Tags: ajax, laravel

Using ajax I want to show up the modal when I click on edit button, but I get error 500 from controller function.
I have checked both functions update2() and edit_assignation() but can't find out what is wrong.
Also, I checked laravel.log trying to find what message it's given but nothing saved there.
Some help on what I am doing wrong and how to fix it will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Route

Route::post('/assign_update2', [AssignationController::class,'update2'])->name('assignation.update2');

Controller

```
public function update2(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->assignation_id;
    //dd($id);
    $assignation = Assignation::find($id);
    //dd($assignation);

    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'data' => $assignation]);
}
```

Script

```
function edit_assignation(caller, id) {
    console.log('CHECKING : ', caller, id);
    $assignation_id = id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ route('assignation.update2') }}",
        data: {
            assignation_id: id,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('LOOK again here = ', data);
            $('#AssignationModal').html("{{ __('evaluation::trad.update_assignation') }}" + data.name);
            $('#assignation_modal').modal('show');
            $('#assignation_id').val(id);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            toastr.error(data.message);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So first the internal server error (500) when clicking on a button. Check the network tab of your chrome dev tools, click on the red error line. Tab 'Response' should have your error response. Laravel.log: make sure your environment is 'local' and that you have turned on debug=true in your .env file

Comment: Looking at your code, it appears that there is some issue in Assignation::find() function. To confirm if everything is working fine in any function, add - echo "Debug 1";exit; first before & then after the function, if you are able to see echo message in both cases, then the problem may be elsewhere.

Comment: @UnderDog Thank you for the remarks but what you've asked before posting asking for help here I checked those

Comment: @nirvana74v I have tried to do as asked and got the echo message but when i dd() the variable nothing is shown. I think that could be the issue

Comment: It would be good if you can also post your find function to understand your problem more

Comment: @nirvana74v, I don't see the find function you're asking I've posted all I thought was good to go also forgot to mention I'm new to Laravel.

Comment: Assignation::find($id); this function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254594/discussion-between-gabjava-and-nirvana74v).